# Digital Ocean Firewall Prevent VPN Client Connectivity

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, firewall

**Info:** I have the below setup, connecting my digital ocean environment to my local network. Using strongswan on the Network A gateway I've made a site to site VPN connection with my meraki on Network B.

**Topology:**

```
           Digital Ocean                             Cisco Meraki

            Network A                                Network B

 Client 1              Gateway               Gateway              Client 2
                                    vpn
10.124.16.3   ---->   10.124.16.2  ======  192.168.14.3  <----  192.168.14.10
                      xx.xx.xx.xx          xx.xx.xx.xx
                           |                    |
                           |                    |
                      no firewall            firewall
```

**Problem:**
This configuration works fine as long as I do not apply a firewall to the gateway machine on the digital ocean network. With no firewall, Client 1 and Client 2 can communicate with each other.

When a firewall is applied in Digital Ocean, they can no longer reach each other. **Even with the firewall wide open (accepts all tcp and udp on all ports)**. The VPN tunnel remains unaffected since all ports are open, and the tunnel is communicating over wan.

**Question:**
Does anyone know why applying a wide-open firewall would prevent private networks from communicating? All other communication on both networks is fine, just subnets cannot speak between networks.

**Edit: Firewall config from Network A** Unfortunately Digital Ocean does not have logging available for their cloud firewalls.

```
inbound
protocol:icmp,address:0.0.0.0/0,address:::/0
protocol:tcp,ports:0,address:0.0.0.0/0,address:::/0
protocol:udp,ports:0,address:0.0.0.0/0,address:::/0

outbound
protocol:icmp,address:0.0.0.0/0,address:::/0
protocol:tcp,ports:0,address:0.0.0.0/0,address:::/0
protocol:udp,ports:0,address:0.0.0.0/0,address:::/0
```

Comment: Configure your firewall to log blocked packets.

Comment: Show us the firewall configuration.

Comment: One additional note. IPSec uses not only UDP but also ESP (protocol number 50) and AH (protocol 51) which operate directly over IP. If the firewall allows only TCP and UDP and no other protocols then you need to use UDP encapsulation. Enabling the firewall logging should clarify the picture.

Comment: Accept all on inbound and outbound?

Comment: Yes currently configured to accept all inbound and outbound. Yet it prevents subnets from communicating. If I completely remove the firewall, communication works again.

Comment: If logging is not available, disable firewall, and do a packet capture to identify required traffic.

Comment: @MattCampbell all TCP and UDP, or esp and ah as well?

Comment: Unfortunately ESP and AH protos not available to configure. Maybe thats the ticket. @vidarlo good idea I will try.

Comment: https://ideas.digitalocean.com/network/p/firewall-ipsec-protocols-50-and-51

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your firewall doesn't allow `ESP` and `AH` protocols, `IPSec` can use [NAT Traversal](https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/features/natTraversal.html). Both `strongswan` and Cisco should be able to detect a restrictive firewall but only when a connection is being established. If you enable the firewall later then your traffic just stops going. You need to restart the connection for NAT Traversal to be enabled. If it still doesn't work you can force `ESP-in-UDP` encapsulation by adding [`forceencaps = yes`](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/connsection) to the connection configuration in the `strongswan` config.